# Appending string column to number column

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation, cell-array

How to append a column of strings to a column of numbers in MATLAB?

For example, I have the string column `wrds` and the number column `occurs`

```
wrds={'the' 'of' 'to' 'and'}'; occurs=[103 89 55 20]';
```

And I want to put them side by side so that they display like this:

```
'the' 103
'of'   89
'to'   55
'and'   20
```

You would thing that this would do the trick:

```
out={wrds occurs}
```

But the output I get when I enter this is:

```
out =
{4x1 cell}    [4x1 double]
```

Which tells me nothing.  How can I do this so that I get to see the actual display of strings and numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the numeric array into a cell array and concatenate:

```
>> out = [wrds(:) num2cell(occurs)]
out = 
    'the'    [103]
    'of'     [ 89]
    'to'     [ 55]
    'and'    [ 20]
```

As a speedier alternative to `num2cell`, I'd suggest `sprintfc`: `out = [wrds(:) sprintfc('%d',occurs(:))]`.

Comment: Now I get: out = {4x1 cell}    {4x1 cell}